# Use polymer Html 5 web components in kendo data grid row template

Tags: html, kendo-grid, polymer, web-component

I've developed a kendo grid with following signature:

```
$('#myDiv').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: someKendoDataSource,
    rowTemplate: function(item) {
            return '<tr><td><div is="div-element"></div></td></tr>';
    }
});
```

In chrome it works, but I see the following warning:

**Attributes on div were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.**

And In Internet Explorer and Firefox, it doesn't work at all and raise the following error at webcomponent.js:

Line: 1799
Error: NotFoundError

This is the error's stacktrace:

```
insertBefore, webcomponents.js, line 1799
Anonymous function, jquery.js, line 5233
domManip, jquery.js, line 5409
before, jquery.js, line 5231
Anonymous function, jquery.js, line 5458
wrapAll, jquery.js, line 8345
```

This is the div-element content:

```
<polymer-element name="div-element" extends="div">
    <template>
        <content></content>
    </template>
    <script>

        Polymer();

    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

My web components are working fine in all other scenarios, but non of them are working in kendo data grid row template.

Note that the grid is working fine when I assign row template as following:

```
$('#myDiv').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: someKendoDataSource,
        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html())
    });
```

Where #rowTemplate is
script id='rowTemplate' type='text/x-kendo-template'
     
/script

But it's not handy for my real scenario which is a little bit different.